# Calculate the difference between two dates in business days

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to calculate the difference in business days between two dates, at my searches I   found the use of functions and gereneate_series() but I would like to search something more practical.

Sample Table:

```
|start_date |end_date |
|2022-06-01 |2022-06-01| 
|2022-05-29 |2022-06-02|
```

Comment: What exactly do you consider to be "business days"? Just "Monday through Friday", or do you require holidays (in what culture/locale/timezone) to be skipped?

Comment: Just monday through friday

Answer (score 2):

What would you consider more practical? It seems `generate_series` and `extract` are specifically made for what you are asking. (see [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=c113cf39b8cc535260e0ced5ef6447c7))

```
select start_date, end_date, count(*)   "Business days"
  from sometable 
 cross join generate_series(start_date,end_date,interval '1 day') gs(dt) 
 where extract(isodow from dt) < 6  
 group by start_date, end_date;
```